# Why does the Sharpe ratio not change when the strategy is leveraged?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, leverage

It has been correctly stated that the Sharpe ratio of a strategy does not change when it is leveraged. I understand [Eric's](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18413/sharpe-ratio-and-leverage) point that leveraging by $n$ multiplies both the return $x$ and volatility $\sigma$ by $n$. I also understand that we fund the leverage at risk free rate, and hence subtract $r(n-1)$ from the return. However, I cannot understand why this would not change the Sharpe ratio (sr) since $$sr = \frac{nx - (n-1)r}{n\sigma} = \frac{n(x-r)}{n\sigma} + \frac{r}{n\sigma} = \frac{(x-r)}{\sigma} + \frac{r}{n\sigma}$$
The sr is different, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Eric Your insight would be very helpful

Comment: should this be a comment to another question?

Comment: Yes it is, but the editor asked me to phrase it as a new question.

Comment: @chollida I have re-framed my question. Hope you retract the negative score assigned to my question.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: your question is very similar to this one: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22478/sharpe-ratio-with-leveraged-etfs/22479#22479

Answer (score 2):

Sharpe ratio = $\frac{r_p - r_f}{\sigma_p}$, where:

- $r_p$ is the expected portfolio return
- $\sigma_p$ is the portfolio's standard deviation
- $r_f$ is the risk free rate.

When you leverage '$n$' times:

1. The leveraged portfolio return is $n r_p - (n-1) r_f$ (subtracting the cost of borrowing the money)
2. The standard deviation increases to $n\sigma$

Hence:

"Leveraged Sharpe ratio" = $\frac{n r_p - (n-1) r_f - r_f}{n\sigma}=\frac{n(r_p-r_f)}{n\sigma}$ = $\frac{r_p - r_f}{\sigma_p}$ = Sharpe ratio.

---

Given any risky asset, one can generate an infinite expected return at the cost of added risk (by leveraging the investment). The Sharpe ratio mitigates "false advertising".